# Ruby script exec "nginx -T" to test config

Tags: ruby, nginx

I want to create a ruby script that takes complex inputs and generates a config file for nginx sites.

I purposely mis-configured the nginx site configs so that they will fail:

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -T
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
...
```

If I do:

```
system("nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -T")
```

the symbolic link `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` turns out not to be part of the config, and my configuration will never fail within my script checking the config.

Can anyone advise?

**Update**

When i execute `system("nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -T")` on IRB, nginx is able to read the symbolic link enabled config. Only when in script mode, the symbolic link is ignored.

Comment: Most probably this may be a user permission issue which cause the file to not be loaded

Comment: definitely not because I'm using root account.

Comment: Run `find / -name "nginx" -type f`and make sure you don't have multiple version of nginx installed